# chmod 755 and 644 is recommended for directories and files, but what owner group?

Tags: php, apache, permissions, server

I read in several places that 755 is good for directories and 644 good for files on servers of php applications.

Now what I haven't figured out, what owner/group should these files have?

let's assume apache runs as www-data.

Comment: If you set them up with user: you, group: www-data then you don't really need to set them as readable to the rest of the users/groups on the system.

Comment: but many pages talk about 755, what are the damned user/groups they want me to use? what you said is what I did, right. I set user me, group www-data. But then I have to use something like 775 and 664, no??